# JEXL – Get current date and time

Tags: jexl

I have to use [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) expression and I need to get current year and month using JEXL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JETT](http://jett.sourceforge.net/expressions/jexl_expressions.html) which allow to invoke static methods in JEXL code:

> ETT extends JEXL to allow references to static methods directly in JEXL Expressions

Then you can call (Java 8) [LocalDateTime.now](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) method to get current date and time:

```
${java.time.LocalDateTime.now()}
```

Comment: I am using Apache-Syncope. 
It prevents using JETT in JEXL expretions... Is there any way without using java?

Comment: can you provide a snippet code of this example ? I've installed JETT but I still having error on executing ${java.time.LocalDateTime.now()}