# DBeaver import tool - transform expression syntax

Tags: mysql, import, transform, dbeaver

I am transferring data into a MySQL database using the DBeaver import tool and I would like to set the value of a column to current date. This would need to go into the transform expression column as highlighted in the image. But I am unable to find the right syntax to do this. Entering CURDATE() or =CURDATE() does not work. Anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: The [docs](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Virtual-column-expressions/) says that expressions are processed using  `Jexl engine`, but [${java.time.LocalDateTime.now()}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50465093/724039) does not work 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with:

```
new("java.util.Date")
```

Thanks to Luuk for the pointer. Here is the reference: https://help.percussion.com/percussion-cm1/developers/advanced/advanced-widgets/jexl-syntax/