# DBeaver CSV Import Transform Expression

Tags: postgresql, csv, dbeaver, jexl

I'm trying to import a CSV into an existing PostgreSQL table using DBeaver Import Tool and I need to transform a numeric value multiplying it by 100.
Someone knows the syntax to be used in the expression?
The [official documentation](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Data-migration) talks about JEXL expressions, but i can't find any example.

I can't post images, but the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175382/dbeaver-import-tool-transform-expression-syntax) is exactly where i need to put the expression.

I was expecting something like:

```
${column}*100
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the columns are exposed as variables so a simple(r) `column * 100` should do.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when importing data from a CSV file, it was necessary to name the column variable exactly as it was listed in the 'Tables mapping' pane of the Data Transfer task editor, for example `Column7 * 100`